# How to create segmentedButtonItems dynamically

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a requirement where i need to create SegmentedButtonItem dynamically based on the number of items in my response.

View: code in my xml view for segmented button:

```
<HBox id="buttonchoice" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center" width="100%">
   <SegmentedButton select="setInitialChoices" id="paymentMethodSelection">
       <items>
           <SegmentedButtonItem id="55" text="Cloud Offering" width="200px"/>
           <SegmentedButtonItem id="56" text="BIT"/>
           <SegmentedButtonItem id="57" text="Others" width="100px" press="_segmentButtonSelected"/>                                            
       </items>
   </SegmentedButton>
</HBox>
```

Controller code:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var that = this;
    if (data.length !== 0) {
        if (data.questions["0"].id === 54) {
            var oInput1 = new sap.m.Text('input1');
            //.questions["0"].question
            oInput1.setText(data.questions["0"].question);
            oInput1.setTooltip("This is a tooltip ");
            var oLayout = this.getView().byId("testform");
            oLayout.addContent(oInput1);
            var oSegBtn = new sap.m.SegmentedButton();
            //var oSegBtn = new sap.m.SegmentedButton();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                oSegBtn = ({
                    items: [
                        new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem(i, {
                            text: "Navigation Off",
                            press: [that.handleButtonPress, this]
                        })
                    ]
                    //  press: [that.handleButtonPress, that]
                });
                //  oSegBtn 
            }
            var oLayout1 = this.getView().byId("choiceQs");
            oLayout1.addContent(oSegBtn);
        }
    }
}
```

Issue:

The above code is creating only one button and adding to content where as the data.length is 3 and ideally i would require 3 buttons to be created and added to the content placed in the view.

Can you please suggest.

Comment: you need to define the array of buttons in outer scope of the loop, so in the loop you will populate this array with SegmentedButtonItem's, and at the end iterate through the created array and call 'addContent'

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the code for the loop. Just create the SegmentedButtonItem within the loop and call `addItem` of SegmentedButton.

```
var oSegBtn = new sap.m.SegmentedButton();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var oSegmentButtonItem = 
            new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({
                text: "Navigation Off",
                press: [that.handleButtonPress, this]
            })
        ;
    oSegBtn.addItem(oSegmentButtonItem);
}
```

See the running example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
     </script>



    <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
     <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
   <HBox id="buttonchoice" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center" width="100%">
     </HBox>
  </mvc:View> 
 </script>


   <script>
    // define a new (simple) Controller type
    sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {

     // implement an event handler in the Controller
     onInit: function() {
     var aMockData = ["item 1","item 2","item 3"];
     var that = this;
     var oSegBtn = new sap.m.SegmentedButton();
     for (var i = 0; i < aMockData.length; i++) {
      var oSegmentButtonItem =
        new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({
     id: "id"+i,
         text: "Navigation Off " + aMockData[i],
         press: [that.handleButtonPress, this]
        })
       ;
      oSegBtn.addItem(oSegmentButtonItem);
     }
     var oHBox = this.getView().byId("buttonchoice");
     oHBox.addItem(oSegBtn);
    },

    handleButtonPress: function(oEvent) {
     var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
     alert(oItem.getText() + " is clicked");
    }
   });


   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()});

   myView.placeAt('content');

  </script>

  </head>
  <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the solution , how to check if already button is available don't create or delete the current and create a new , because this would create again and again on just navigation too